# Understanding Output of Partial Function

Tags: function, idris

Given the following partial function (no output for a `Nothing` input):

```
f : Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
f (Just 42) = Just 42
```

the REPL shows the following:

```
*Lecture> f $ Just 42
Just 42 : Maybe Int

*Lecture> f Nothing
f Nothing : Maybe Int
```

What is the meaning of `f Nothing`'s output?

Answer (score 2):

Idris won't reduce expressions involving calls to partial functions without matching patterns.  In other words, this is just the REPL's way of presenting an undefined or "bottom" value.  Presumably if you make that call in an executable then you'll get a runtime error instead.

From [the tutorial](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#totality):

> And although [a partial function] typechecks and compiles, it will not reduce (that is, evaluation of the function will cause it to change):

```
-- Unsafe head example!
unsafeHead : List a -> a
unsafeHead (x::xs) = x

unsafe> the Integer $ unsafeHead [1, 2, 3]
1 : Integer
unsafe> the Integer $ unsafeHead []
unsafeHead [] : Integer
```